# How to convert the string to object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to convert this string into object

```
var str = "res=[xyz=name,abc=address]";
```

I need below output :

```
var obj = {xyz: "name",abc:"address"}
```

I tried to convert this by using json.parse and split but I can't get the result .can anyone help to do this ?

Comment: show full code please :)

Comment: where does that string come from?  it looks like it's a formatted output.  what generated it?

Comment: "I tried to convert this by using json.parse"...it's clearly not JSON. Anyway...you might want to try using a regular expression

Comment: Your title says "array" but your question says "object". Which do you want? Also, please show what kind of research you've done, as there are many questions about parsing strings on Stack Overflow.

Comment: It's come from a response

Comment: Using `JSON.Parse()` won't get you anywhere, because that's not JSON.  If you extract what's inside the `[` and `]` then you can split by `,` to get an array of strings, then split each one by `=`  to get a key/value pair.  Then you just `obj[key] = value`.  Please post your code so we can help fix it.

Comment: @parithiinfo why isn't the resource that gives you that response formatting it as JSON?

Comment: You might like to change the source / whatever is generating the response to create actual JSON - would make your life *soo* much easier.

Comment: @archer this what I tried , but it goes long way right ?

Comment: As I said, if you post your code we can help.

Comment: Edit your question and use code tags (or indent by 4 spaces) - don't add code as a comment.

Comment: Archer this is third party service response ..

Comment: @parithiinfo Post your code and we can help you.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One more Implementation:

```js
//str format "res=[xyz=name,abc=address]"
function stringToObject(str){
  const extractedStr = str.substring(str.indexOf("[")+1,str.indexOf("]")-1);
  return extractedStr.split(",").reduce((acc,keyVal)=>{
    acc[keyVal.split("=")[0]] = keyVal.split("=")[1];
    return acc;
  },{});
}

console.log(stringToObject("res=[xyz=name,abc=address]"));
```

Comment: I wonder why I was voted down and you not - same complex parsing, just mine is vastly easier to read and understand

Answer (score 1):

This code works with the string given. It is also very readable for noobs

```js
var str = "res=[xyz=name,abc=address]";
str = str.split("res=")[1]
  .replace("[",'{"')
  .replace("]",'"}')
  .replace(/=/g,'":"')
  .replace(/,/g,'","');

res = JSON.parse(str);
console.log(str,"\n",res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it:

```js
//  format your input like this, comma separated, and key=val
const str = "xyz=name,abc=address"
const obj = str.split(',').reduce((acc, keyVal) => {
  const [key, val] = keyVal.split('=')
  acc[key] = val
  return acc
}, {})

console.log(obj)
// { xyz: "name", abc: "address" }
```

Comment: But why spend time changing the input and then spend time parsing it? If he could change the input to suit your script, then he could just deliver a proper object to begin with

Comment: I just meant to grab the values inside of `res=[ ]` It's unclear what the rest of his code may include so I left this part out not knowing what the best way to do it would be.

Answer (score 0):

> Another implementation

```js
let str = "res=[xyz=name,abc=address]";

let convertStrToObject = (str) => {
  return str
    .substring(5, str.length - 1)
    .split(",")
    .reduce((acc, item) => {
      acc[item.split("=")[0]] = item.split("=")[1];
      return acc;
    }, {});
};

console.log(convertStrToObject(str));
```